# How to refresh or reload a page in React Native without refreshing the entire bundle or app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-navigation

I want to find a way that simulates the pull to refresh but in simple page using  or  or any things else beside the build in hooks of react navigation (useFocusEffect)?
to reload all the actions and all the functionalities inside that hitted route

- i tried useFocusEffect